# Прошу помочь с задачей с циклом

Tags: javascript

У меня есть JavaScript код. Как сделать чтобы на каждой итерации к head i paragraph добавлялося число и увеличивалось на 1? Спасибо большое

```
   for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    let b = document.createElement('div');
    let p = document.createElement('p');
    let c = document.createElement('h1');
    c.innerText = 'head';
    p.innerText = 'paragraph';
    b.appendChild(c);
    b.appendChild(p);
    document.body.appendChild(b);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    let b = document.createElement('div');
    let p = document.createElement('p');
    let c = document.createElement('h1');
    c.innerText = 'head_' + i;
    p.innerText = 'paragraph_' + i;
    b.appendChild(c);
    b.appendChild(p);
    document.body.appendChild(b);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)